# Check if a compilation was made (Makefile)

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that compile 2 binary, and display messages for each compilation and when all compilations are done:

```
$(NAME):       $(NAME_S) $(NAME_C)
               @echo "\033[31mCompilation done!\033[0m"

$(NAME_S):     $(OBJS_S)
               @cc -o $(NAME_S) $(OBJS_S)
               @echo "\033[32mCompilation server done!\033[0m"

$(NAME_C):     $(OBJS_C)
               @cc -o $(NAME_C) $(OBJS_C)
               @echo "\033[32mCompilation client done!\033[0m"
```

My problem is when the two binary are "up to date" and I send a make, the message "Compilation done!" is displayed (and it's normal); but I would like to have the default message, generated by the makefile itself ("make: Nothing to be done for $(NAME)").

In advance thanks.

Comment: You've defined a rule for `$(NAME)`, so it wouldn't be true that there's "nothing to be done for $(NAME)".

Comment: If there is no change between two compilation (on my .c) the makefile put this message (if I remove the first echo, there is).

Comment: How about "No more compilation to be done"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create the file of your target, so make will only try to remake that target when its prerequisites have changed.

e.g.

```
$(NAME):       $(NAME_S) $(NAME_C)
               @echo "\033[31mCompilation done!\033[0m"
               @touch $(NAME)
```